# Wordpress add custom post type to menu

Tags: wordpress

On the main menu as shown below I currently have Posts and Projects.  I'd like to create another category below Projects called Research. How would I add this option to the menu please?

[image]

Comment: Google is your best friend. https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no code provided, we can't show you what is wrong or not working.  So you need to look at some info to help get you further.  Wordpress provides a lot of information on this.  As stefan stated, you can do a quick google search on custom post types and there are plenty of tutorials and information.  You can find information on registering the post type [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

You can also download plugins that make custom post types very easy and fast to implement.

As far as adding your custom post type to the admin panel Treehouse has a great tutorial taking you through the entire process from start to finish [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are add post type using

```
<?php register_post_type( $post_type, $args ); ?>
```

don't forget to add this argument

```
'show_in_menu' => true
```

for more help click [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)